# NSDate: Extract Date ONLY

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm using the code below to extract the date only from NSDate.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"Now Date %@",now);
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    format.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
    NSString *stringDate = [format stringFromDate:now];
    NSDate *todaysDate = [format dateFromString:stringDate];
    NSLog(@"Today's Date without Time %@", todaysDate);
```

Log:

```
2014-06-21 12:27:23.284 App[69727:f03] Now Date 2014-06-21 19:27:23 +0000
2014-06-21 12:27:23.285 App[69727:f03] Today's Date without Time 2014-06-21 07:00:00 +0000
```

Why am I getting: `07:00:00 +0000` at the end?

I would like to get an NSDate in the in the following format:

```
2014-06-21 00:00:00 +0000
```

Having `0`'s for time, seconds, etc. is not important.

Comment: +7 looks like a timezone, yours maybe? :)

Comment: Yes, it is time zone I think.  Can't get rid of that?

Comment: format.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:1];
Set your timezone parameter to resolve this error (Change 1 to your timezone)

Comment: @tyt_g207  that worked beautiful!  Can you please include that as your answer and I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
```

should work

Answer (score 5):

Another solution: using NSCalendar:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:1]]; // I'm in Paris (+1)
NSDateComponents *comps = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];

comps.hour = 0;
comps.minute = 0;
comps.second = 0;

NSDate *newDate = [cal dateFromComponents:comps ];

NSLog(@"date: %@",newDate);
```

Adjust timezone param, you will receive something like: date: 2014-06-21 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: Thanks.  but this approach is VERY slow/expensive!

Comment: In fact, both NSDateformatter & NSCalender. I don't know which one is slower. To improve the performance, take a look at this link. http://sam.roon.io/how-to-drastically-improve-your-app-with-an-afternoon-and-instruments. I'll add another reply (using <timer.h> like in that article)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the time, NSDate is not the right storage structure for you. An NSDate represents a specific moment in time - there is no NSDate without a time. What you're seeing is the logged description of an NSDate, which is the full printout in GMT.

If you want to keep track of the year, month and day only, then use NSDateComponents instead, and extract only the components you are interested in. You can then use the components object and pass it around as you like.

Comment: @new2ios if you're seeing that, you're not using date components and are therefore probably commenting on the wrong answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

With the code above, the NSDate object will HAVE time. But the string will be a date only text.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code using .

```
#include <time.h>

- (NSDate *)dateFromISO8601String:(NSString *)string {
    if (!string) {
        return nil;
    }

    struct tm tm;
    time_t t;

    strptime([string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", &tm);
    tm.tm_hour = 0;
    tm.tm_min = 0;
    tm.tm_sec = 0;
    tm.tm_isdst = -1;
    t = mktime(&tm);

    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:t + [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]];
}


- (NSString *)ISO8601String:(NSDate*)aDate {
    struct tm *timeinfo;
    char buffer[80];

    time_t rawtime = [aDate timeIntervalSince1970] - [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

    strftime(buffer, 80, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", timeinfo);

    return [NSString stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}


NSString *currentDateStr = [self ISO8601String:[NSDate date]];

NSDate *dateWithoutTime = [self dateFromISO8601String:currentDateStr];

NSLog(@"currentDateStr: %@",currentDateStr);
NSLog(@"dateWithoutTime: %@",dateWithoutTime);
```